# is deformation possible on ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The Question is very simple, i just want to know , if is possible the deformation of objects ( like when you take a ball of gum) on ROS, i know that in gazebo doesn't (some weeks ago).
thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51717/is-deformation-possible-on-ros/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, ROS only uses Gazebo as its simulation environment. Gazebo will support deformable physics once bullet is integrated as mentioned in :

> http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/305/spawning-animated-deformable-objects-in-gazebo/#314

---

Originally posted by [isura](https://answers.ros.org/users/1583/isura/) with karma: 403 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2